# Excel VBA user defined function to find images in folder

Tags: vba, excel

I have image names in excel sheet as:

```
16094_1.jpg
16095_1.jpg,16095_2.jpg
```

names could be single or multiple in a cell separated by commas.
they are stored in location

```
"C:\Users\Jatin\Desktop\Jatin\november\17-nov\images"
```

i want to create user defined function(formula)
that can find images in desired location, whether they exist or not.
for example,

```
=findimage("path",imagename)
=findimage("C:\Users\Jatin",a1)
```

Comment: You can use `Dir()` for this.

Comment: please explain, i am beginner in vba.

Comment: You should watch this series: [Excel VBA Introduction](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5).  I posted an answer because I thought your concept was interesting. I really shouldn't have posted an answer because SO is not a code writing service, it makes me look bad among my peers.  In the future please try to make some attempt to write the code yourself.  It really doesn't matter how good your code is, it only matters that you are trying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
Function hasImages(Path As String, ImageList As String)
    Dim results
    Dim x As Long
    results = Split(ImageList, ",")
    If Not Right(Path, 1) = "\" Then Path = Path & "\"

    For x = 0 To UBound(results)
        results(x) = Len(Dir(Path & results(x))) > 0
    Next

    hasImages = Join(results, ",")
End Function
```

Comment: thanks thomas, i need one more help from you... i wanna check if i save 4 images in folder but write only 3 image names in excel, then it should also write in result column that how many images are in folder. We can count images in folder by keyword "apple" if image names are apple_1, apple_2..... please help on this thomas... will be very thankful...

Comment: Please post another question and link it to me.  Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40858211/excel-vba-user-defined-function-to-find-images-in-folder-match-excel-names-to-f

Answer (score 1):

You could try with this function:

```
Function IfFileExist(strPath As String, strFileName As String)
    IfFileExist = False
    If Len(Dir(strPath & "\" & strFileName)) > 0 Then
        IfFileExist = True
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: this worked but only for single image, what if i have multiple image names in cell. like this : 

    16095_1.jpg,16095_2.jpg

Comment: 1st, you could split names into separate cells. 2nd. what results should be produced as you have three states like both True, both false, one True or even more results like (True, False), (False, True), etc... therefore it would be better to check each file individually