# Excel VBA user defined function to find images in folder (match excel names to folder names of images)

Tags: vba, excel

Currently i am using a function to match image names from excel sheet to image folder, but i want one more thing... that if i save image and forget to add its name in excel then it should show me that i forget to add name.
for example if i save 3 images in image folder

```
16095_1.jpg,16095_2.jpg,16095_3.jpg
```

and i add image names in excel sheet as

```
16095_1.jpg,16095_2.jpg
```

then it should warn me that i forget one image name in excel cell.

my image name format is - 16095_1.jpg,16095_2.jpg

function i am using is...

```
Function findimage(Path As String, ImageList As String)
Dim results
Dim x As Long
Dim dc 'double comma
results = Split(ImageList, ",")
If Not Right(Path, 1) = "\" Then Path = Path & "\"
For x = 0 To UBound(results)
results(x) = Len(Dir(Path & results(x))) > 0
Next
dc = InStr(ImageList, ",,")
If dc = 0 Then
findimage = Join(results, ",")
Else
findimage = ("Double_comma")
End If
End Function
```

Comment: You can use `Dir()` to loop over all the files at the specified location, and check them against the list of files you pass in.

Comment: please explain, i am beginner in VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function takes a folder path and a variable number of patterns (See [MSDN - Parameter Arrays (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/538f81ec.aspx)).  Using the [MSDN - Dir Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk008ty4(v=vs.90).aspx) to iterates over the file names in the folder path and compares them against the patterns with the [MSDN - Like Operator (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx) to count the number of files that match the patterns.

**Usage:**

- getFileCount("C:\Users\Owner\Pictures","*.gif","*.png")
- getFileCount("C:\Users\Owner\Pictures","*.gif"
- getFileCount("C:\Users\Owner\Pictures","apple_*.gif","banana_*.gif", "orange_##.*")
- getFileCount("C:\Users\Owner\Pictures","#####_#.gif")

---

```
Function getFileCount(DirPath As String, ParamArray Patterns() As Variant) As Integer
    Dim MyFile As String
    Dim count As Integer, x As Long
    If Not Right(DirPath, 1) = "\" Then DirPath = DirPath & "\"

    MyFile = Dir(DirPath, vbDirectory)

    Do While MyFile <> ""
        For x = 0 To UBound(Patterns)
            If MyFile Like Patterns(x) Then
                count = count + 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        MyFile = Dir()
    Loop
    getFileCount = count
End Function
```

Comment: thanks a lot.... but you created this seperate... but i want this to work with my vba...

Comment: can you please merge these two.... so that result would be... True,True,False (4).... 4 show that there are 4 images in folder